# Don't let a user to use same item for different select inputs

Tags: vue.js

I'm developing an OTC trading interface and a request for quote interface for that with `Vue.js`. My goal is to don't let user use same *item* for two different *select inputs*.

Select input:

```
<v-select
 v-model="yousendselect"
 :items="items"
 :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
 label="You get"
 required
></v-select>
```

Select input 2:

```
<v-select
 v-model="yougetselect"
 :items="items"
 :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
 label="You get"
 required
></v-select>
```

Items:

```
items: [
 'Bitcoin',
 'Ethereum',
 'Litecoin',
 'Ripple',
],
```

If an user selects **Bitcoin** for `v-model="yousendselect"`, user won't be able to select **Bitcoin** for `v-model="yougetselect"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
computed: {
  itemsYouSend() {
    return this.item.filter(s => s !== this.yousendget)
  },
  itemsYouGet() {
    return this.item.filter(s => s !== this.yousendselect)
  }
}
```

Select input:

```
<v-select
 v-model="yousendselect"
 :items="itemsYouSend"
 :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
 label="You get"
 required
></v-select>

<v-select
 v-model="yougetselect"
 :items="itemsYouGet"
 :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']"
 label="You get"
 required
></v-select>
```

Comment: Hi, answer didn't work after adding to `<script>`, I updated answer (added items) which might be helpful.

Comment: You need to add it to the computed properties: see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Send</h2>
      <select v-model="yousendselect">
        <option :value="undefined">---</option>
        <option v-for="item in itemForSendSelect" :key="item" :value="item">{{ item }}</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Get</h2>
      <select v-model="yougetselect">
        <option :value="undefined">---</option>
        <option v-for="item in itemForGetSelect" :key="item" :value="item">{{ item }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        "Bitcoin",
        "Ethereum",
        "Litecoin",
        "Ripple",
      ],
      yousendselect: undefined,
      yougetselect: undefined,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    itemForSendSelect() {
      return this.items.filter(i => i !== this.yougetselect);
    },
    
    itemForGetSelect() {
      return this.items.filter(i => i !== this.yousendselect);
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```